# issues with parsing JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to create a basic PHP function for a wordpress site that reads over a JSON response from an API and takes the data of each animal to be added to a custom post.

I'm having some trouble figuring out the correct way to parse the JSON & loop over the animals and their respective data.

I know its just my not understanding the JSON structure correctly and I'm not parsing it in the right way - so hoping that someone can direct me on the correct approach.

Here is my Function - the issue at the moment is the loop is not working and i'm not able to get the animals data to populate the fields.

```
<?php

//Get advertised animals from ARMS and generate custom post
function get_advertised_animals(){

  $animals = [];
  $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://##my-test-API##'));

  $results = json_decode($results);

  if ( ! is_array($results) || empty ($results) ){
    return false;
  }

  $animals[] = $results;

  foreach ($animals[0]['Animals'] as $animal){

    $animal_slug = sanitize_title($animal->Name . '-' . $animal->FFAR_ID)

    $inserted_animal = wp_insert_post([
      'post_name' => $animal_slug,
      'post_title' => $animal->Name,
      'post_type' => 'animal',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_content' => $animal->Biography,
      'post_excerpt' => $animal->Blurb

    ]);

    // Make sure we have the post id
    if ( is_wp_error( $inserted_animal )) {
        continue;
        }

    //Array of all data from the API mapped to the ACF field IDs
    $fillable = [
      'field_5e807346d13f2' => 'Gender',
      'field_5e807363d13f3' => 'Breed',
      'field_5e80736fd13f4' => 'Colour',
      'field_5e807376d13f5' => 'DateOfBirth',
      'field_5e807410d13fb' => 'ExtListURL',
      'field_5e8b1d251e542' => 'AdoptionFee'
      'field_5e807420d13fc' => 'Image1',
      'field_5e8074c2d13fd' => 'image2',
      'field_5e8074cad13fe' => 'Image3',
      'field_5e8074d7d13ff' => 'Image4',
      'field_5e8073b0d13f7' => 'activityLevel',
      'field_5e8073bcd13f8' => 'GoodWithDogs',
      'field_5e8073e7d13f9' => 'GoodWithCats',
      'field_5e8073f7d13fa' => 'GoodwithChildren',
      'field_5e8073a7d13f6' => 'Size'.
      'field_5ea4e481081ed' => 'id'
    ];

    foreach ( $fillable as $key => $name ) {
        update_field ( $key, $animal->$name, $inserted_animal );

      }

  }


}

?>
```

Here is the example JSON that is sent back by the API

```
{
    "Animals": [
        {
            "Id": 13,
            "Name": "Denver",
            "FFAR_ID": "D200002",
            "Type": "Dog",
            "Breed": "Kelpie x Collie",
            "DateOfBirth": "2020-04-08",
            "Colour": "tan and black",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "AdoptionFee": 750.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/D200002_01_159430",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Small",
            "GoodWithDogs": "Yes",
            "GoodWithCats": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithChildren": "Unknown",
            "ActivityLevel": "High"
        },
        {
            "Id": 22,
            "Name": "Diana",
            "FFAR_ID": "C200012",
            "Type": "Cat",
            "Breed": "Domestic Short Hair",
            "DateOfBirth": "2020-02-21",
            "Colour": "Grey/White",
            "Gender": "Female",
            "ExtListURL": "https://www.petrescue.com.au/listings/797984",
            "Biography": "Diana is a beautiful tabby kitten, she’s white with grey spots running down her tail and one grey smudge next to her right ear. If you love sitting down and binge-watching shows, Diana is the purfect companion to join you.\r\n\r\nShe loves finding places to hide when she’s cold, either hiding in the couch or in the TV cabinet. Diana will be fine by herself in her new home as long as she gets a few extra scratches under the chin and behind the ear. She’s more than capable to entertain herself (but wi",
            "AdoptionFee": 200.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Small",
            "GoodWithDogs": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithCats": "Yes",
            "GoodWithChildren": "Unknown",
            "ActivityLevel": "Medium",
            "Blurb": "Playful and Gentle"
        },
        {
            "Id": 18,
            "Name": "Katie",
            "FFAR_ID": "C200009",
            "Type": "Cat",
            "Breed": "Domestic Medium Hair",
            "DateOfBirth": "2020-04-06",
            "Colour": "Tabby and white",
            "Gender": "Female",
            "Biography": "This stunning girl will win the hearts of everyone ",
            "AdoptionFee": 250.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Small",
            "GoodWithDogs": "No",
            "GoodWithCats": "Yes",
            "GoodWithChildren": "Yes",
            "ActivityLevel": "Medium",
            "Blurb": "Beautiful Katie"
        },
        {
            "Id": 15,
            "Name": "Lily (and Sooty)",
            "FFAR_ID": "C200006",
            "Type": "Cat",
            "Breed": "Birman",
            "DateOfBirth": "2007-05-01",
            "Colour": "White with black point",
            "Gender": "Female",
            "ExtListURL": "https://www.petrescue.com.au/listings/797968",
            "Biography": "Sooty and Lily are a great pair for a calm, quiet, and loving home. Sooty is a super easy going deaf boy who loves cuddles all day long. True to his bread he is vocal and with his deafness he can be loud.\r\n\r\nLily prefers to keep more to herself, but when she decides she likes you she’ll come and sit on your lap rolling over and asking for cuddles. She particularly loves scratches on the head and bum! They spend most of the day sitting staring outside the window at the world moving past, but she’",
            "AdoptionFee": 75.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Small",
            "GoodWithDogs": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithCats": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithChildren": "No",
            "ActivityLevel": "Low",
            "Blurb": "A majestic pair"
        },
        {
            "Id": 9,
            "Name": "Mickey",
            "FFAR_ID": "C200002",
            "Type": "Cat",
            "Breed": "Domestic Medium Hair",
            "DateOfBirth": "2020-04-06",
            "Colour": "Black and white",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Biography": "Mickey is a super loving, cuddly, playful kitten ",
            "AdoptionFee": 250.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Small",
            "GoodWithDogs": "Yes",
            "GoodWithCats": "Yes",
            "GoodWithChildren": "Yes",
            "ActivityLevel": "Medium",
            "Blurb": "Affectionate "
        },
        {
            "Id": 14,
            "Name": "Rory",
            "FFAR_ID": "D200003",
            "Type": "Dog",
            "Breed": "Kelpie x Collie",
            "DateOfBirth": "2020-04-08",
            "Colour": "black with a white sock",
            "Gender": "Female",
            "AdoptionFee": 750.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Medium",
            "GoodWithDogs": "Yes",
            "GoodWithCats": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithChildren": "Unknown",
            "ActivityLevel": "High"
        },
        {
            "Id": 12,
            "Name": "Sooty (and Lily)",
            "FFAR_ID": "C200005",
            "Type": "Cat",
            "Breed": "Birman",
            "DateOfBirth": "2007-05-01",
            "Colour": "White with black point",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "ExtListURL": "https://www.petrescue.com.au/listings/797968",
            "Biography": "Sooty and Lily are a great pair for a calm, quiet, and loving home. Sooty is a super easy going deaf boy who loves cuddles all day long. True to his bread he is vocal and with his deafness he can be loud.\r\n\r\nLily prefers to keep more to herself, but when she decides she likes you she’ll come and sit on your lap rolling over and asking for cuddles. She particularly loves scratches on the head and bum! They spend most of the day sitting staring outside the window at the world moving past, but she’",
            "AdoptionFee": 75.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Small",
            "GoodWithDogs": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithCats": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithChildren": "No",
            "ActivityLevel": "Low",
            "Blurb": "A majestic pair"
        },
        {
            "Id": 6,
            "Name": "Terry",
            "FFAR_ID": "C200001",
            "Type": "Cat",
            "Breed": "DSH",
            "DateOfBirth": "2020-03-02",
            "Colour": "Grey Tabby",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "ExtListURL": "https://thatsite.com",
            "Biography": "Terry says meow",
            "AdoptionFee": 100.00000000,
            "Image1": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image2": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image3": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Image4": "https://devarms.blob.core.windows.net/images/",
            "Size": "Small",
            "GoodWithDogs": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithCats": "Unknown",
            "GoodWithChildren": "Unknown",
            "ActivityLevel": "Low",
            "Blurb": "meow"
        }
    ],
    "Result": {
        "Success": true
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Change below area:

```
     $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://##my-test-API##'));
    
      $animals = json_decode($results);
    
      if ( ! is_array($results) || empty ($results) ){
        return false;
      }
    
    //  $animals[] = $results;
    
      foreach ($animals['Animals'] as $animal){
   // Your code here
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Manash,  

 The pretty much sorted it -   I also found  i had to update the JSON decode to   $animals = json_decode($json_array,true); so the result was an array and not an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the object `Animals` from the json so you should change it to:

`foreach ($animals[0]->Animals as $animal) {`

Comment: Thanks Chaska,  Your response and Manash' helped me resolve this.